# OMP 2.0 Nested For Loops

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

As I'm unable to use omp tasks (using visual studio 2015) I'm trying to find a workaround for a nested loop task. The code is as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        for (i = 0; i < largeNum; i++)
        {
#pragma omp single
        {
            //Some code to be run by a single thread
            memset(results, 0, num * sizeof(results[0]));
        }
#pragma omp for
            for (n = 0; n < num; n++) {
                //Call to my function
                largeFunc(params[n], &resulsts[n])
            }
        }
#pragma omp barrier
    }
```

I want all my threads to execute largeNum times, but wait for the memset to be set to zero, and then i want the largeFunc be performed by each thread. There are no data dependencies that I have found.

I've got what the omp directives all jumbled in my head at this point. Does this solution work? Is there a better way to do without tasks?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `#pragma omp parallel for` for the `for` loop with `largeFunc`, and remove the rest of the omp stuff? That loop seems to be the only one that you want to run in parallel.

Comment: I don't want to split the largeNum loop across the threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just this code?

```
#pragma omp parallel private( i, n )
for ( i = 0; i < largeNum; i++ ) {
    #pragma omp for
    for ( n = 0; n < num; n++ ) {
        results[n] = 0;
        largeFunc( param[n], &results[n] );
    }
}
```

As far as I understand your problem, the intialisation part should be taken care of without the need of the `single` directive, provided the actual type of `results` supports the assignment to 0. Moreover, your initial code was lacking of the `private( i )` declaration. Finally, the `barrier` shouldn't be needed .

Comment: @Giles I don't want the largenum to be split across the threads, just the inner loop. Does this implementation have an implied barrier after the inner for?

Comment: This implementation will spawn a team of threads, with all of them executing the full range of the `i` iterations, and inside each of the iterations, sharing the work on the `n` loop. There is an implicit barrier at the end of the `omp for` directive preventing any thread of the team from starting a new `i` iteration before all threads have finish the current one. So all in all, my take is that it does what you wanted (although I fail to see the reason you wanted in the first place - benchmarking maybe).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want all your threads to execute largeNUM ? do you then depend on index i inside your largeFunc in someway if yes

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < largeNum; i++)
    {
#pragma omp single
    {
        //Some code to be run by a single thread
        memset(results, 0, num * sizeof(results[0]));
    }
#pragma omp barrier

// #pragma omp for  -- this is not needed since it has to be coarse on the outermost level. However if the below function does not have anything to do with the outer loop then see the next example
        for (n = 0; n < num; n++) {
            //Call to my function
            largeFunc(params[n], &resulsts[n])
        }
    }

}
```

If you do not depend on i then

```
    for (i = 0; i < largeNum; i++)
    {
        //Some code to be run by a single thread
        memset(results, 0, num * sizeof(results[0]));

 #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int n = 0; n < num; n++) {
            //Call to my function
            largeFunc(params[n], &resulsts[n])
        }
    }
```

However I feel you want the first one. In general you parallelise on the outermost loop. Placing pragmas in the innerloop will slow your code down due to overheads if there is not enough work to be done.

Comment: No dependency. Won't placing the pragma inside cause a thread join? I'm trying to keep the threads forked to miniimize overhead

Comment: So you dont have any sort of dependency whatsoever ? then you are lucky and can use `#pragma omp for nowait` The nowait will remove the implied barrier for you.

Comment: No dependencies except that I want all the threads to after the internal for.

Comment: Yes then put the `#pragma omp parallel` inside the outermost for loop just before the first inner loop. You can also use nowait as I mentioned. If there is no implicit barrier before the next operation or if you dont need one this saves you a lot of overhead. But just test out the speed benefits yourself. These suggestions highly depend on what you do inside your loop and where the major workload is.